# SharePoint Online - Possible to create a list item with an ID which was already deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, id

I have a SharePoint Online list where the ID of the latest item created is 2006.

The list has some custom parent, child functionality where the ID of the parent item should be smaller than the child item.

But for one of the categories, the parent item with ID 1390 has got deleted few months back but no one noticed it till now until recently. If we create the parent item now, it will get created with ID 2007 and since this ID will be greater than it child items, the solution will not work for this category.

My question is, Will it be possible to create a new item in SharePoint online(using Powershell preferably) with an custom or user specific ID which got deleted already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, we cannot create or update sharepoint **list item id** by our own, it is auto generated by SharePoint, this is the default behavior.

You may refer to the below MSDN article for the list item id :

[ListItem.Id property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539237(v%3Doffice.15))

Answer (score 1):

Habibur is correct. You cannot change the list item id just which is a builtin field controlled by SharePoint. You may try to create a new custom number column and re-fill it with the desired number.

As it is a custom column, you can always handle it later by. And surely you may have to arrange the references already made.